# Netbeans Navigator Open Path

Tags: netbeans

Im using Netbeans 7.3 at the moment, I've used it since 6.5 I believe.

In the Navigator "Projects" tab, is it possible to open up your File Browser such as Windows Explorer from there by right clicking or using a hotkey?

I have to drag files and unzip things often, and I get tired of flipping through applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin called [QuickOpener](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43217/quickopener). You can select a file in the Projects window then launch a custom command, for example:

`C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe  ${currentFile}`